# Unable to automatically debug "xxxx". Attaching to the server process failed. Mixed mode debugging is not supported on Windows 64-bit platforms

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging

We are getting the above error when we try and run our tests in debug mode.

We have a .net solution written in C#, which we have developed using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP.

We have now got new machines :). Windows 7 64 bit.

The solution has several wcf host and web services host, it also runs some windows workflows.

It appears that it is trying to stop at a break point in the code, in other places it stops and asks if it should break.

Question is:

- Why is this happening for only some dll's / services?
- Can I configure it to not break on error, but just fail the test and keep going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of this error by adding the following to my config (app.config or web.config)

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

A bit more info [here](http://www.creativecodedesign.com/node/24).